# clang fails to build libc++ (redefine nothrow_t, new, delete, new[], delete[] ) against new MSVC 2019 and Windows SDK 10.0.17763.0

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, libc++

It seems there are 5 symbols conflicted: `nothrow_t`, `new`, `delete`, `new[]`, `delete[]`

```
[2/37] Building CXX object lib\CMakeFiles\cxx_shared.dir\__\src\algorithm.cpp.obj
FAILED: lib/CMakeFiles/cxx_shared.dir/__/src/algorithm.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe  /nologo -TP -DNDEBUG -D_ALLOW_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL_MISMATCH -D_ALLOW_MSC_VER_MISMATCH -D_CRTBLD -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_STDIO_ISO_WIDE_SPECIFIERS -D_LIBCPP_BUILDING_LIBRARY -D_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_PRAGMA_SYSTEM_HEADER -IC:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\libcxx-master\include -fms-compatibility-version=19.00 --target=x86_64--windows -D_LIBC_NO_VCRUNTIME -D_LIBCPP_NO_VCRUNTIME /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG   /std:c++14 -Wall -Wextra -W -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-long-long -Werror=return-type -Wextra-semi -Wno-user-defined-literals -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-c++11-compat -Wno-undef -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-gnu-include-next -Wno-gcc-compat -Wno-zero-as-null-pointer-constant -Wno-deprecated-dynamic-exception-spec -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-old-style-cast -Wno-deprecated -Wno-shift-sign-overflow -Wno-double-promotion -Wno-error -EHsc /Zl /showIncludes /Folib\CMakeFiles\cxx_shared.dir\__\src\algorithm.cpp.obj /Fdlib\CMakeFiles\cxx_shared.dir\ -c C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\libcxx-master\src\algorithm.cpp
In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\libcxx-master\src\algorithm.cpp:10:
In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\libcxx-master\include\random:1645:
In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\libcxx-master\include\istream:163:
In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\libcxx-master\include\ostream:137:
In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\libcxx-master\include\ios:215:
In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\libcxx-master\include\__locale:23:
In file included from C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\libcxx-master\include\support/win32/locale_win32.h:15:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\xlocinfo.h:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\yvals.h:9:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\crtdbg.h:13:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\vcruntime_new_debug.h:10:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\vcruntime_new.h(34,16): error: redefinition of 'nothrow_t'
    struct nothrow_t {
           ^
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\libcxx-master\include\new(123,25): note: previous definition is here
struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS nothrow_t {};
                        ^
```

This is my CMAKE. (also tried 19.20)

```
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:/Program Files (x86)/Ninja/ninja.exe" 
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe" 
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fms-compatibility-version=19.00 --target=x86_64--windows -D_LIBC_NO_VCRUNTIME" 
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe" 
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fms-compatibility-version=19.00 --target=x86_64--windows -D_LIBC_NO_VCRUNTIME -D_LIBCPP_NO_VCRUNTIME" 
-DCMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/lld-link.exe" 
-DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/lld-link.exe" 
-DLLVM_USE_LINKER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/lld-link.exe" 
-DLLVM_PATH="C:/Program Files/LLVM" -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED=YES 
-DLIBCXX_ENABLE_STATIC=NO -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_LIBRARY=YES 
"C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/libcxx-master"
```

This is my SDK

```
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\lib\x64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64
```

Can I make it work? Where to send issue to whom?

Comment: You are using [clang], not [visual-c++].  Expecting one compiler to be happy about the #include files of another will lead to tears.  If you want to use Clang then you should install the VS-specific flavor of it.  Go back to the installer, select Modify. The checkbox ought to be located under the "Individual components" tabs.  Used to be named "Clang/C2" in VS2017.

Comment: @HansPassant This set of CMAKE parameters works fine with MSVC 2017. I succesfully built with it before. I just wonder how I can make it work with MSVC 2019?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face the same issue with VS2019.
I removed no_runtime flags but set

`-DCMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE="lld-link.exe -flavor link" ^
-DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE="lld-link.exe -flavor link" ^`

Added `-flavor link` and it linked successfully. I did not test exceptions but test program with `std::thread` compiles and runs same as with `cl` compiler.

UPD: basic try-catch with `std::exception` thrown works

UPD: full cmake batch (your paths may vary!)

```
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="D:/Programming/ninja-build/ninja.exe" ^
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="clang-cl.exe" ^
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fms-compatibility-version=19.00 --target=x86_64--windows" ^
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="clang-cl.exe" ^
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fms-compatibility-version=19.00 --target=x86_64--windows " ^
-DCMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE="lld-link.exe -flavor link" ^
-DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE="lld-link.exe -flavor link" ^
-DLLVM_USE_LINKER="lld-link.exe" ^
-DLLVM_PATH="C:/Program Files/LLVM" -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED=YES ^
-DLIBCXX_ENABLE_STATIC=NO -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_LIBRARY=YES ^
"D:\Programming\cpp_sandbox\libcxx-9.0.0.src"
```

Comment: I tried without `-flavor link`, it works also, What does the `-flavor link` do?

Comment: It tells clang linker to use MSVC linker. There is other problem now - I can't use this lib without MSVC because it cannot `#include_next <wchar.h>` even though I tried to add -MT to linker flags - it doesn't help, it just needs some "other" system headers to be (but I don't want MSVC to be present on my PC...). Maybe you have Idea how to build it completely independent?

Comment: I never tried this myself but I think you may try `clang++ --driver-mode=g++` with msys2 gcc static standard lib `libstdc++.a` => https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc . Nevertheless, I'm certained that will be depend on OS msvcrt.dll (NT CRT not visual studio's) anyway.

Comment: @sandthorn the problem is that by default clang invokes linker with `-deafultlib:libcmt` and I have no idea how to fix it except from splitting build to `clang -c...` and `lld-link -defaultlib:msvcrt...`

Comment: @sandthorn can you also show me an example on how do you build using NT library?